# Angular2/TypeScript: error TS2345: Argument of type 'String' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, string, angular, typescript, wrapper

I have the following code, which I am using to create a Casino Management System:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }            from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }        from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject }           from 'rxjs/Subject';

import { SearchService } from './search.service';
import { Data } from './datatypings';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'casino-search',
  templateUrl: 'search.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'search.component.css' ],
  providers: [SearchService]
})

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  data: Observable<Data[]>;

  private searchTerms = new Subject<String>();

  constructor(
    private searchService: SearchService,
    private router: Router) {}
  // Push a search term into the observable stream
  search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = this.searchTerms
      .debounceTime(150)        // wait for 150ms pause in events
      .distinctUntilChanged()   // ignore if next search term is same as previous
      .switchMap(term => term   // switch to new observable each time
        // return the http search observable
        ? this.searchService.search(term)
        // or the observable of empty data if no search term
        : Observable.of<Data[]>([]))
          .catch(error => {
        // TODO: real error handling
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.of<Data[]>([]);
      });
  }

  gotoDetail(data: Data): void {
    let link = ['/detail', data.id];
    this.router.navigate(link);
  }
}
```

However, when I attempt to transpile this code from TypeScript to JavaScript I get this error:

```
app/data/search.component.ts(37,37): error TS2345: Argument of type 'String' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'string' when possible.
```

Now, I've fixed the error simply by changing `String` to `string` within the angle braces but I want to be able to proceed in future without creating similar errors, and also to write the best code I can... So I'm wondering if someone could clear this up for me:

I think I understand that a parameter with a wrapper class is something which encapsulates a primitive class and provides some sort of additional, usually interfacing related, behaviour (correct me if I'm wrong here), and I see why it might then not be possible to assign the contents of what is essentially a broader declared variable type to the more simple primitive, there is another aspect of the error message which interests me, that is:

Why would it be preferable to use type 'string' over type 'String' in Angular2/Typescript in such a general sense as the error seems to imply? What is it which makes this preferential?

Comment: try to change it to `new Subject<string>(); "small s"`

Comment: Yeah, I changed it before I asked the question. What I wanted to know, though, is what makes the predefined wrapper class `String` preferable over the primitive `string` type, as per the recommendation in the error message.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Not at the moment, but I'm going to a small conference soon (giving a talk! Wooottt!) and the topic will be Angular2 and TypeScript, so I'll ask around and see if anyone knows the solution.

Answer (score 7):

```
private searchTerms = new Subject<String>();
```

change it to

```
private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
```

**`String`** is a **`class`** and **`string`** is a **`datatype`**.

Comment: Yeah, I know. What is the difference between the Typescript library class `String` and the TypeScript datatype `string` which should cause me to use the datatype over the class in all instances where such a thing is possible (as per the error message), though, was my question.

Comment: `Subject` method/API will emit data later on. `Subject<string>()` so it tells which type of data will be emited. Generally subject can emit `string type` data and obviously not `String class` type data. So...

Comment: So it's preferable use the String wrapper class in general because the extra data in the wrapper class does not interface cleanly (or perhaps at all? I wonder if the wrapper class can be 'made' to interface, but that's seperate...) Subject API? Perhaps there is a more general rule about not adding additional complexity by using a wrapper class unless absolutely required and the Subject method issue is just one example of one wrapper class (I assume Subject is also a wrapper class?) interfacing poorly or not at all because of the additional complexity added by the wrapper?

Comment: its hard to say until looking inside of subject's definition.